# UIImageView not showing picture from imagePickerController

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, storyboard

I've looked at a lot of solutions which, sadly, did not work for me. I used this code to create an imagePickerController:

```
  @IBAction func takePhoto(sender: UIButton) {
    imagePicker =  UIImagePickerController()
    imagePicker.delegate = self
    imagePicker.sourceType = .Camera
    imagePicker.mediaTypes = [kUTTypeImage as String]
    imagePicker.allowsEditing = false

    presentViewController(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, _didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {
        let pickedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage 
        imageView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit
        imageView.image = pickedImage
        dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```

But still the image I take on the camera doesn't show up in the imageView. I also imported the correct delegates. When I try to print the imageView.image to the console it returns `nil`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try `func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {`

Comment: Works! What does the underscore do to make it work?

Comment: Your method declaration needs to be written exactly the same as the picker delegate method otherwise it will never be called. You should always let Xcode autocomplete it for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this code. Hope it will help you.

```
func cameraPhoto(){

        imagePicker.allowsEditing = true
        imagePicker.delegate = self
        imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera
        imagePicker.cameraCaptureMode = .Photo
        imagePicker.cameraDevice = .Front;
        presentViewController(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)

 }

func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {


    let chosenImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage] as! UIImage
}
```

Thanks